# How to save NULL in SQL DB using c#

Tags: save

I need to save just NULL in a column of SQL DB Table. but it is saving as 'NULL' or "" (blank). How to save just NULL?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special object: DBNULL. You can handle this as null.

Comment: DBNULL.Value throws error "cannot implicitly convert System.DBNULL to string. when it is converted using ".toString()" or Convert.ToString(); it is saving with single quotes 'NULL' . I want to save without single quotes. Please Help!

Comment: Are you trying to create a SQL String? Then try creating null without parentheses. Better way: Look in the documentation and get familiar with SQL Parameters. Ist's  easier to maintain and faster at the end.

Comment: Working. Thank You.